# Missing templates during Kotlin project creation

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Within JetBrains tutorial is this info regarding [creating new Kotlin project](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/jvm-get-started.html#create-an-application)
[image]

But I can see only this --> i.e. without Project Template

[image]

Both the Idea and tutorial is for IntelliJ 2020.2 (I use Community Edition, but I did not find any note regarding different tutorials for different editions)
I am probably missing something... but don't know what

edit:
I would say that I have Kotlin plugin installed
[image]

Comment: Could you check under _File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Kotlin_ if you have installed the Kotlin plugin in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @OliverO. I would say so - I have added another print screen above, Current Kotlin plugin version 1.3.72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade the Kotlin Plugin in IntelliJ IDEA to version 1.4. The new project wizard has been introduced in [Kotlin 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#new-flexible-project-wizard).

Comment: Super strange, I have just installed IntelliJ to my system and it had the older version (1.3.72) of the Kotlin plugin... after your advice all is solved. Thanks

Comment: As Kotlin 1.4 has just been released, it seems like there is a delay before the new plugin gets packaged into IDEA. Good that it could be solved that easily.